# Chrome update to new tab disables automatic typing (bug)

Tags: google-chrome

I am using OS X on a Macbook Pro laptop.

Ever since the update to Chrome where they changed the style of the new tab, I have been experiencing a weird bug. So far I have only seen it displayed on my macbook, other places I use the browser it works as expected.

My normal workflow is to press `Ctrl + T` and start typing, usually because I am doing a search or I know the URL of the page I am visiting (and relying on the omnibar to auto-fill).

However, after the update I can no longer automatically start typing. Even if I select the text field in the middle (below the Google logo), nothing happens. Also, all of my 'Most visited pages' are just grey boxes.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJd85.png

Occasionally it will work as normally, usually if something else is loading in another tab (heavy pages taking 5+ seconds to load) or if I re-open a lot of tabs from my last browsing (`Cmd + Shift + T`), but I haven't been able to reproduce it faithfully.

Anyone familiar with this bug? I have tried disabling various extensions, but nothing changes it.

Comment: Does disabling various extensions include all of them?

Comment: Yes, although I haven't tried doing it simultaneously. Might have to do that.

Comment: That's what I meant. Try disabling them all.